# Listing a manager's name who has the oldest employee

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to select a manager's first and last name who has the oldest employee, however I'm getting some issues because whenever I run this:

```
SELECT PERSONAL_DETAILS.FIRST_NAME, PERSONAL_DETAILS.SURNAME, MIN(STAFF.join_date) AS Join_Date
FROM STAFF

INNER JOIN PERSONAL_DETAILS
ON STAFF.PERSONAL_ID = PERSONAL_DETAILS.PERSONAL_ID

WHERE STAFF.ROLE_NAME = 'staff'
GROUP BY PERSONAL_DETAILS.FIRST_NAME, PERSONAL_DETAILS.SURNAME
```

Because the where clause is set to find all staff members it returns all staff members, if I were to change it to manager it then returns all managers. I understand why it does but I'm really not sure how to solve my problem here.

I want it so the result set to return a managers first and last name along with the date of their oldest employee.

I feel its not about how my tables are setup because I can't change them in my situation, its more to do with how can I write a SQL statement which will allow me to select/ match a name with the oldest date when there are multiple tables involved, because I need to join the staff table to personal_details for example to get hold of the managers first and last name but I need those names to match against the oldest date for example.

Comment: Given a staff member, how do you know who their manager is? That's not apparent to me from the code example given. Is there something like a MANAGER_ID on the STAFF or PERSONAL_DETAILS tables?

Comment: The STAFF table also has the managers in there, along with which branch they work at, so if the employees are at the same branch they have that manager who has the same branch_id

Comment: Gordon Linoff script works but it returns the employees first and last name instead of the managers.

Comment: did you try mine?

Comment: Yes and it does the same as Gordon Linoff script, gives the employees first and last name, when I am hoping to get it to return the managers first and last name but with the date of the oldest employee

Comment: so how does your manager data relates to the employee? i think at the moment you only have staff details and join date.

Comment: @Erdss4 you still did not clear, how to find employee and manager relation from your tables ? Can you add DDL of your tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try building this up piece-wise. First - it appears you're looking for the person or persons who have been employed by the company for the longest period of time, rather than the oldest employees. I base that on the fact that you're using `MIN(JOIN_DATE)` to determine the employees to select, rather than e.g. `MIN(BIRTH_DATE)`. So, OK - to find the earliest JOIN_DATE we use the MIN function, as you've already done:

```
SELECT MIN(JOIN_DATE)
  FROM STAFF
  WHERE ROLE_NAME = 'staff'
```

Great, that gets us the earliest JOIN_DATE for all "staff" people (as opposed to "manager" people). Now to find the person or persons with that JOIN_DATE we use the above as a subquery:

```
SELECT *
  FROM STAFF emp
  WHERE ROLE_NAME = 'staff' AND
        JOIN_DATE = (SELECT MIN(JOIN_DATE)
                       FROM STAFF
                       WHERE ROLE_NAME = 'staff')
```

OK, so now we've got the staff members who have been with the company the longest. Now, to find their manager (per your comment) we'd use the BRANCH_ID from STAFF to find the manager:

```
SELECT *
  FROM STAFF mgr
  WHERE mgr.ROLE_NAME = 'manager' AND
        mgr.BRANCH_ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT BRANCH_ID
                            FROM STAFF emp
                            WHERE ROLE_NAME = 'staff' AND
                                  JOIN_DATE = (SELECT MIN(JOIN_DATE)
                                                 FROM STAFF
                                                 WHERE ROLE_NAME = 'staff')
```

Now we have to get to the PERSONAL_DETAILS table to find the manager's name, so we'll join the PERSONAL_DETAILS into the above query

```
SELECT pd.FIRST_NAME, pd.SURNAME
  FROM STAFF mgr
  INNER JOIN PERSONAL_DETAILS pd
    ON pd.PERSONAL_ID = mgr.PERSONAL_ID
  WHERE mgr.ROLE_NAME = 'manager' AND
        mgr.BRANCH_ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT BRANCH_ID
                            FROM STAFF emp
                            WHERE ROLE_NAME = 'staff' AND
                                  JOIN_DATE = (SELECT MIN(JOIN_DATE)
                                                 FROM STAFF
                                                 WHERE ROLE_NAME = 'staff')
```

### EDIT

Now, frankly, all those subqueries and such give me hives and gas and make my hand sore from all that indentation, so let's introduce something new: the Common Table Expression (CTE). A CTE is defined *before* the SELECT and is basically a little table all its own you can use like any other table in your main query:

```
WITH MIN_STAFF_JOIN_DATE AS (SELECT MIN(JOIN_DATE) AS MIN_JOIN_DATE
                               FROM STAFF
                               WHERE ROLE_NAME = 'staff'),
     EARLIEST_EMPLOYEES AS (SELECT s.*, d.FIRST_NAME, d.SURNAME
                              FROM STAFF s
                              INNER JOIN PERSONAL_DETAILS d
                                ON d.PERSONAL_ID = s.PERSONAL_ID
                              INNER JOIN MIN_STAFF_JOIN_DATE msjd
                                ON msjd.MIN_JOIN_DATE = s.JOIN_DATE
                              WHERE s.ROLE_NAME = 'staff'),
     MANAGERS AS (SELECT m.*, d.FIRST_NAME, d.SURNAME
                    FROM STAFF m
                    INNER JOIN PERSONAL_DETAILS d
                      ON d.PERSONAL_ID = m.PERSONAL_ID
                    WHERE m.ROLE_NAME = 'manager')
SELECT ee.FIRST_NAME AS EMPLOYEE_FIRST_NAME,
       ee.SURNAME AS EMPLOYEE_SURNAME,
       ee.JOIN_DATE,
       mgr.FIRST_NAME AS MANAGER_FIRST_NAME,
       mgr.SURNAME AS MANAGER_SURNAME
  FROM EARLIEST_EMPLOYEES ee
  INNER JOIN MANAGERS mgr
    ON mgr.BRANCH_ID = ee.BRANCH_ID
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works however, it does not return the longest employed employee date with the managers name, so where the last sub query is, I am trying to figure out how to get that into the result set; the one with the MIN(JOIN_DATE)

Comment: a well documented answer

Comment: Thank you for your help, it worked and allowed me to find out about CTE's Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need aggregation here.  Think `order by` and `fetch first 1 row only`:

```
SELECT pd.FIRST_NAME, pd.SURNAME, s.join_date
FROM STAFF s INNER JOIN
     PERSONAL_DETAILS pd
     ON s.PERSONAL_ID = pd.PERSONAL_ID
WHERE s.ROLE_NAME = 'staff'
ORDER BY s.join_date
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

(This works in Oracle 12c+.  In earlier versions you need a subquery.)

Having shown this, I doubt it does what you want.  I would expect the this to be the `staff` person's name, not their managers.  You can figure that one out.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT P.FIRST_NAME, P.SURNAME, X.join_date AS Join_Date
FROM PERSONAL_DETAILS P
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT STAFF.PERSONAL_ID,STAFF.JOIN_DATE FROM STAFF WHERE STAFF.ROLE_NAME = 'STAFF' AND JOIN_DATE = (SELECT MIN(JOIN_DATE) FROM STAFF WHERE STAFF.ROLE_NAME = 'STAFF')
) X On X.PERSONAL_ID = P.PERSONAL_ID
```

1st step : Get Min Join Date 
2nd step : Get Staff details from 1st step  
3rd step : Get Manager details from 2nd step